# How to change context message on a multibranch project using declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently i'm aware that it's possible to change the context message with  [GitHub pull request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin). But since currently , I'm only using GitHub Organization projects on Jenkins due the massive amount of repositories that  we have , its possible to change the context message via declarative pipeline?

Current:
[image]

Expected:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with:

```
    pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Stage #1") {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
                githubNotify gitApiUrl: 'https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3', context: 'something test', description: 'This commit is being built',  status: 'PENDING'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
          githubNotify gitApiUrl: 'https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3', context: 'something test', description: 'It works',  status: 'SUCCESS'
        }
        failure {
          githubNotify gitApiUrl: 'https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3', context: 'something test', description: 'This commit cannot be built',  status: 'FAILED'
        }
    }
}
```

Plugin used: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-githubnotify-step-plugin